# No windows 10 update for lumia 930

Tags: windows-10-mobile, update, nokia-lumia-930

I've installed Update Advisor and it tells

> Good news! Your phone is eligible for upgrade to Windows 10. We are
>   working with your mobile operator and phone manufacturer to make the
>   upgrade available for your phone and you'll see a notification when
>   it's ready

But there is no update for a long time already, while my friend who has the same phone and mobile operator already got an update several months ago. I'm from Ukraine. How can I check if there's something wrong with my phone or force Windows 10 update by myself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your phone model is eligible for Windows 10 mobile. You can install Windows 10 mobile for sure. Try these solutions:

**Solution 1:**

1. Uninstall the [Upgrade Advisor app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/apps/upgrade-advisor/9nblggh0f5g4).
2. Restart your phone.
3. Reinstall the [Upgrade Advisor](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/apps/upgrade-advisor/9nblggh0f5g4)

---

**Solution 2:**

It is a workaround actually.

1. Install the Windows Insider app. (Don't worry I guiding to install the stable build finally and not the insider).
2. Enroll in the Insider program. it is advised to choose the Release Preview ring.
3. *Optional step:* For better performance hard reset your phone.
4. Opt-out of Insider preview program. You can refer to [this article](http://www.windowscentral.com/stop-getting-insider-build-windows-10-mobile) for full details.
5. Now your phone will stay in the latest build for preview release i.e) on Windows 10 Mobile build itself.
6. It will be running that insider build for a while until the public release for your build or newer is released. Don't worry Release Preview ring is highly stable and public release is very close.

Comment: @Mykyta Glad to see that. Enjoy using Windows 10.