# How can I upgrade my Lumia 1520 to Windows Phone 10?

Tags: windows-10-mobile

I bought my new Lumia 1520 smartphone in the U.S. but live in Israel. Microsoft’s Upgrade Advisor says my phone is eligible for its Windows Phone 10 Upgrade but Microsoft limits the availability of this upgrade to certain countries and mobile operators (see https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/Windows-10-specifications?type=mobile) and has not delivered it to my operator. Can anyone help me upgrade my phone? Thank you very much.

Comment: Keeping operator aside for a min, hav you tried using WiFi connection?

Comment: Check this question  - http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/13492/18061

Answer (score 1):

Your phone model is eligible for Windows 10 mobile<sup>[[1]](http://www.windowscentral.com/here-are-all-windows-phones-are-eligible-windows-10-mobile-upgrade)</sup>. You can install Windows 10 mobile for sure. Try these steps:

**Solution:**

It is a workaround actually.

1. Install the Windows Insider app. (Don't worry I guiding to install the stable build finally and not the insider).
2. Enroll in the Insider program. it is advised to choose the Release Preview ring.
3. Install the updates via Wi-Fi.
4. *Optional step:* For better performance hard reset your phone.
5. Opt-out of Insider preview program. You can refer to [this article](http://www.windowscentral.com/stop-getting-insider-build-windows-10-mobile) for full details.
6. Now your phone will stay in the latest build for preview release i.e) on Windows 10 Mobile build itself.
7. It will be running that insider build for a while until the public release for your build or newer is released. Don't worry Release Preview ring is highly stable and public release is very close.